# PHP displaying different images at different times on html webpage

Tags: php, html

Hi I have this PHP code which I expect should be working however it is currently showing a blank page.

How can I get this working on my HTML site? As when I look on the php file on the local host it doesnt come up with anything just blank. What I want this for is so that different times of the day a different images appear, this is for a radio show. But I cant seem to get it working properly.

```
<?php
$h = date('G'); //set variable $h to the hour of the day
$d = date('w'); //set variable $d to the day of the week.
$year = date('Y'); //set variable $year to the current year
//G is the date key for hours in 24 format (not 12), with no leading 0s, like 02.
// Adjust 2 hour offset for MST below.
$h = $h-2;

    // MONDAY SCHEDULE
    if ($d == 1 && $h >= 12 && $h < 14) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 14 && $h < 16) $img =  'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 1 && $h >=16 && $h < 18) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 18 && $h < 20) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 20 && $h < 22) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 22 && $h < 24) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 19) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h < 0) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    
    // TUESDAY SCHEDULE
    if ($d == 2 && $h >= 12 && $h < 14) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h >= 14 && $h < 16) $img =  'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h >=16 && $h < 18) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h >= 18 && $h < 20) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h >= 20 && $h < 22) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h >= 22 && $h < 24) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h >= 19) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 2 && $h < 0) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    
    // WEDNESDAY SCHEDULE
    if ($d == 3 && $h >= 12 && $h < 14) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h >= 14 && $h < 16) $img =  'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h >=16 && $h < 18) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h >= 18 && $h < 20) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h >= 20 && $h < 22) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h >= 22 && $h < 24) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h >= 19) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 3 && $h < 0) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    
    // THURSDAY SCHEDULE
    if ($d == 4 && $h >= 12 && $h < 14) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h >= 14 && $h < 16) $img =  'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h >=16 && $h < 18) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h >= 18 && $h < 20) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h >= 20 && $h < 22) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h >= 22 && $h < 24) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h >= 19) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 4 && $h < 0) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    
    // FRIDAY SCHEDULE
    if ($d == 5 && $h >= 12 && $h < 14) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h >= 14 && $h < 16) $img =  'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h >=16 && $h < 18) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h >= 18 && $h < 20) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h >= 20 && $h < 22) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h >= 22 && $h < 24) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h >= 19) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
    else if ($d == 5 && $h < 0) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
```

Comment: Blank page often means PHP error, I’d turn on error reporting and/or check the logs. Whenever you have an `if` statement, you should always have, or at least test, a final `else`, which I’m not seeing.

Comment: Nothing in a log that I can see? And is there any errors in the code?

Comment: @mplungjan sorry I dont quite understand what you mean?

Comment: I have copied your code, however now I have an image error and I am not sure why its popping up?

Comment: Sorry @mplungjan if im being silly here, are you saying I need to echo each one in the code for each hour set?

Answer (score 0):

- you do not have a default image
- you do not echo the image to the page at the end of the page
- your schedules are the same for each day and your are setting the same image for every time

I would expect this:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/556ecb6463298fcfa82f93372a000b9738d911d9

```
<?php

  $h = date('G'); //set variable $h to the hour of the day 
  $d = date('w'); //set variable $d to the day of the week.
  $year = date('Y'); //set variable $year to the current year
//G is the date key for hours in 24 format (not 12), with no leading 0s, like 02.
// Adjust 2 hour offset for MST below.
  $h = $h-2;

  $img="img/hosts/off_air.jpg"; // default

    if ($h >= 12 && $h < 14) $img = "img/hosts/test$d_12to14.jpg";
    else if ($h >= 14 && $h < 16) $img =  "img/hosts/test$d_144to16.jpg";
    else if ($h >=16 && $h < 18) $img = "img/hosts/test$d_16to18.jpg";
    else if ($h >= 18 && $h < 20) $img = "img/hosts/test$d_18to20.jpg";
    else if ($h >= 20 && $h < 22) $img = "img/hosts/test$d_20to22.jpg";
    else if ($h >= 22 && $h < 24) $img = "img/hosts/test$d_22to24.jpg"; 
    //else if ($h >= 19) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg'; // already handled 
    else if ($h < 12) $img = 'img/hosts/test$d_morning.jpg';
    
    echo "<img src=\"$img\" />";
    
?>
```

Now you can have images like

`test1_12to14.jpg` for Monday from 12 to 14
and
`test3_22to24.jpg` for Wednesday from 22 to 24

Comment: Okay so I have done that however the offline isnt coming up or the new images?

Comment: You of course need to rename my images or yours. Offline no longer comes up because I changed the last entry to `if ($h < 12)`

Comment: I renamed it of course. I just changed the images and it seems to be working. I just need to make sure it changes on the hour. And oh right okay so we need to use that one as an offline?

Comment: And how do I then make it so it displays on my html page as this PHP code is in djtimes.php file

Comment: I have no idea what djtimes.php is -some kind of `include` statement perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

you have not declare the scope or condition for hour less than 12
your first condition should be

```
if ($d == day_number && $h < 12) $img = 'img/hosts/test2.jpg';
```

[this is your code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2030cc82ae202960b822b35471d752a200c1546)